# dom referenceing vs storing dom reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between the following statements?

```
$("#txt").val("123");
```

and

```
var txt=$("#txt");
txt.val("123");
```

Which one is most efficient?

Comment: both are the same... second one is efficient if you are accessing `$("#txt")` multiple times because in that case you will be doing the dom lookup only once... assuming you are not running `var txt=$("#txt");` again and is only reusing the variable `txt`

Comment: test by yourself at http://jsperf.com, it depends on the browser and commonly the storing will more efficient since not storing will search the entire DOM on the document again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Both version go through the motion of finding a relevant dom element and setting a value

There is no benefit to doing one or the other unless you need to reference it again. Consider this:

```
if ( $("#txt").val()!='123' )
  $("#txt").val("123");

// vs. 

var txt=$("#txt");
if ( txt.val()!='123' )
  txt.val("123");
```

The latter is more efficient because you are only looking for the element once.

But if you are simply setting it.. either way in your example is going to be the same amount of work. *Slightly* more overhead from setting a variable first, but nothing to shake a stick at...but even the above situation isn't likely worth shaking a stick at either, unless you enjoy nickel and diming fractions of microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, if you need only once to target a desired element selector:

```
$("#txt").val("123"); // is just fine
```

But most of the time programmers need to reference multiple times to the same element, and to increase the overall application performance they store the selector into a variable memory slot:

```
var txt  = $("#txt");
var input = $("#someInput");

input.on('input', function() {
   txt.val( this.value ); // *
});

txt.addClass('selected'); // JS says "hey I know this guy!"
```

- where at this point JS doesn't need to go all over the document looking for your `#txt` input on every keyup / keydown or other *input* events. Can you imagine the benefit?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be operating on the value of `#txt` more than once, it is best to cache the selector as you did in the second version, if you're going to be using the object multiple times. In the end, you probably won't notice any considerable performance increases by using one method v. the other.

As for quantitative data:

```
versionOne(): 0.0359999998472631
versionTwo(): 0.02500000037252903
```

This test seems to suggest that the first one is slower, using `window.performance`. When running this, make sure to empty your browser cache.

```
(function() {
    var v1 = [];
    var v2 = [];
    function avg(data) {
        var sum = 0
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sum += data[i];
        }
        return sum / data.length;
    }
    function versionOne() {
        $("#txt").val('hello');
    }
    function versionTwo() {
        var txt=$("#txt");
        txt.val("123");
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var start = window.performance.now();
        versionOne();
        var end = window.performance.now();
        v1.push(end - start);

        var start = window.performance.now();
        versionTwo();
        var end = window.performance.now();
        v2.push(end - start);
    }

    console.log("versionOne(): " + avg(v1));
    console.log("versionTwo(): " + avg(v2));

})();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RNGa/4/)

Comment: You're doing it wrong. jQuery does cache the selector for you. If you executed the [tests the other way round](http://jsfiddle.net/4RNGa/1/), the result would be the opposite.

Comment: Regardless, I knew that, as I stated in the first sentence. The "test" was just to provide a visualization. I'm not sure I understand where you saw that my answer has merit for a downvote.

Comment: I think the answer is not useful because the quantities are wrong and quite misleading. Btw, measuring them in milliseconds is hinting at inaccuracy.

Comment: With [this setup](http://jsfiddle.net/4RNGa/3/), I'm getting results around `jquery selector2: 0ms (109µsec); jquery selector1: 0ms (59µsec); jquery selector2: 0ms (52µsec)` (yes, executing `$("#txt")` a second time is twice as fast as the first)

Comment: @Bergi If invalidate your cache (do a hard reload) then you should see that `versionTwo` is consistently faster than `versionOne`

Comment: Not when versionTwo is the first invocation, no. After Sizzle's cache is filled, they perform quite equally (unmeasurable differences). | Edit: In your updated test suite (4) with 100000 iterations and `Date.now` in Opera 12.16 I'm getting `versionOne(): 0.03874; versionTwo(): 0.03865`

Comment: In the end, if a programmer is going to want to operate on the object more than once, they should cache it.